# Issue with Django 1.6 Registration Form, submitting data

Tags: python, django

Having a problem with my user registration form in django, the form wont submit the data and register the information, the registration form just clears out and loads the page again, with an empty form. Any ideas as too what I am doing wrong?

**Forms.py**

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):

    real_name=forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Real Name','required':True}))
    birthday=forms.DateField(label=_(u"birthdate(mm/dd/yy)"),widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1900, now[0]+1)),required=False)
    city=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'City','required':True}))
    state=forms.CharField(max_length=2, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'State','required':True}))
    image = forms.ImageField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        """ To Specify the fields from User model and the extension of the user model from django, and to prevent abstraction"""
        fields = ['real_name', 'birthday','city','state','image']





    def clean_real_name(self):
        last_name = self.cleaned_data['real_name']

        return real_name

    def clean_birthday_name(self):
        birthday = self.cleaned_data['birthday']

        return birthday

    def clean_city(self):
        city = self.cleaned_data['city']

        return city

    def clean_state(self):
        state = self.cleaned_data['state']

        return state

    def clean_image(self):
        image = self.cleaned_data['image']

        return image
```

**Views.py**

```
def register(request):
    template_var={}
    form = RegisterForm()  
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method=="POST":
           form=RegisterForm(request.POST.copy(),request.FILES)
           if form.is_valid():
                user=request.user

                real_name=form.cleaned_data["real_name"]
                birthday=form.cleaned_data["birthday"]
                city = form.cleaned_data["city"]
                state = form.cleaned_data["state"]   
                reqfile = request.FILES["image"]
                resgisteruser=ProfileUser.objects.create( birthday=birthday, user_title='Fashionista', user_points=0,
                    city=city, state=state, image=reqfile)
                resgisteruser.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dashboard"))          
    template_var["form"]=form        
    return render_to_response("registration/register.html",template_var,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: my guess - you are not logged in !! Also, this is a great candidate for modelforms

Comment: Did you look at the logs?

Comment: How do you look at logs? Is their a command through the terminal to look?